# How do I retrieve client ID and secret in Azure to use creating and destroying Virtual Machines?

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

Day in and out I often need to create virtual machines in the Azure, I am thinking of using Azure API to automate this task. However, the Azure API requires the client ID and secret for authentication purpose.

I did search Google on how can I retrieve this info, but everything points me to register a new Application to get a client and secret ID. But in my case, I just want to launch and terminate VMs and do not understand the rationale behind registering an APP for this purpose.

Can I get the client and sec Id without registering an APP? If yes, can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call the azure rest api, e.g. [`Virtual Machines - Create Or Update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/createorupdate), you need the access token in the request. The AD App is used to get the access token, if you want to use the `client id` and `secret` to get the access token, the App is necessary.

See this link : [How to: Use the portal to create an Azure AD application and service principal that can access resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal)

If you don't want to register the App, you can click the `Try it` in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/createorupdate), login with your account and copy the `Authorization` token, refer to the screenshot. Besides, if you want to get the access token programmatically, I recommend you to register the AD App and use the AD App to get the access token, it is convenient.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your time. Can you please let me know on what context should I create an App? because I do not understand why it is required and what is the use of it. I have not gone through the docs that you have posted, I am doing it now.

Comment: @VigneshSP In your case, I think you should create an App, it is a good way. (In general, if we want to access the azure resources, we will create the App.) I suppose you are new to azure ad, it seems a little difficult to let you know all the relationships right now.

Comment: @VigneshSP After creating the App, add it as a role(e.g.`owner`) under the `Access control (IAM)` of your subscription in the portal, more details see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal), then your app will have the permission to create/delete the VM(also other permissions, it depends on the role you added), then you can refer to this python demo to create/delete the VM: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/virtual-machines-python-manage

Comment: thank you, now I have a fair understanding of the whole scheme. Thanks again for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to register an app, because that is the identity your script will use.
Any user or app interacting with a subscription needs an identity in the linked AAD + access granted via Azure RBAC.

Register a Web App/API, and then just grab the client id (application id) and create a key (secret).

Then go to the subscription / resource group / resource and give the app the necessary access from the Access Control IAM tab.